# Show that $f$ is Riemann Stieltjes integrable?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, riemann-integration

Given $f : [0, 1] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a bounded function which is continuous on $[0,1]$ except at $1/2$. Let $\alpha(x) = x^2$.  No further description of function $f$  is given. How do I show that $f$ Riemann Stieltjes integrable with respect to $\alpha$?

Comment: Welcome to MSE! Interesting question. What have you tried to answer the question? What issues do you have to? Can you recall the definition of a Riemann Stieltjes integrable function? Thanks to update your question accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

It follows from the equality $$(R-S)\int_0^1 fdg =(R)\int_0^1 f(x)\alpha'(x) dx$$